# How to implement smooth scrolling in JavaFX ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I've been researching about this for a time now but to no luck I couldn't still do it properly.

Basically I want to make the scrolling of my ScrollPane smooth similar to Mozilla browser's scrolling.

What I did so far is that I applied timeline animation to these events:

```
myPane.setOnScroll(EventHandler<ScrollEvent>)

myPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, EventHandler<ScrollEvent>)

myPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(ChangeListener<Number>)
```

but none of these worked.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: i don't have an answer but if you know if its possible to access the mouse wheel acceleration you could try playing with those numbers. For example, an event for OnMouseScroll or something, you could try overriding a mouse acceleration value so you can control it.